# Select Statement error javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

There is no update on selected items but am getting exception, any help is appreciated.

Exception trace:

```
    viewOrders....
Jul 05, 2017 3:40:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Camel1Orderfulfillment] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly] with root cause
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy269.getOrderDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.pluralsight.orderfulfillment.order.OrderController.viewOrders(OrderController.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Service:

```
public interface OrderService {
   List<Order> getOrderDetails();
}
```

ServiceImpl:(Only getters are used)

```
@Override
    public List<Order> getOrderDetails() {
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

        try {

            for (Iterator<OrderEntity> iterator = orderRepository.findAll().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

                OrderEntity entity = iterator.next();
                CustomerEntity customerEntity = entity.getCustomer();
                Customer customer = new Customer(customerEntity.getId(), customerEntity.getFirstName(),
                        customerEntity.getLastName(), customerEntity.getEmail());
                orders.add(new Order(entity.getId(), customer, entity.getOrderNumber(), entity.getTimeOrderPlaced(),
                        entity.getLastUpdate(), OrderStatus.getOrderStatusByCode(entity.getStatus()).getDescription()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("An error occurred while retrieving all orders: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return orders;
    }
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {
   @Inject
   private OrderService orderService;
   @RequestMapping(value = "/viewOrders", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String viewOrders(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("orders", orderService.getOrderDetails());
      return "viewOrders";
   }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: "eclipse"

group = 'com.pluralsight.camel'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

description = """"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7



repositories {

     maven { url "http://central.maven.org/maven2/" }
}
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE') {
            exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version:'1.5.2.RELEASE') {
            exclude(module: 'spring-aop')
    }
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version:'1.0.0.GA'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version:'4.3.1.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version:'4.3.5.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version:'4.3.5.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version:'1.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version:'1.7.6'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.6'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version:'1.7.6'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.14'
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version:'1.7.4'
    compile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version:'2.2'
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version:'1'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version:'9.1-901.jdbc4'
    compile group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version:'1.4'
    compile group: 'jstl', name: 'jstl', version:'1.2'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version:'1.9.9'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-jsp', version:'2.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-el', version:'2.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:'3.3.2'
    compile group: 'net.sf.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version:'2.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring', version:'2.13.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring-javaconfig', version:'2.13.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-test-spring', version:'2.13.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit-dep', version:'4.10') {
exclude(module: 'hamcrest-core')
    }
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version:'1.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'1.9.0'
    compile(group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.0.1') {
       /* This dependency was originally in the Maven provided scope, but the project was not of type war.
       This behavior is not yet supported by Gradle, so this dependency has been converted to a compile dependency.
       Please review and delete this closure when resolved. */
    }
    compile(group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'jsp-api', version:'2.2') {
       /* This dependency was originally in the Maven provided scope, but the project was not of type war.
       This behavior is not yet supported by Gradle, so this dependency has been converted to a compile dependency.
       Please review and delete this closure when resolved. */
    }
}
```

Comment: please, add an implementation of OrderService

Comment: Do you have @Transactional on any methods or classese (like OrderService)?

Comment: Do you have any other exceptions in logs?

Comment: Pls check I have included entire exception logs, will be due to some version issue?

Comment: from logs I see that Spring creates proxy for OrderService and uses it to manage transaction. I'm not sure why it's happens, but I think that your application configured to use transaction for service. Try to add @Transactional(noRollbackFor = Exception.class) to getOrderDetails() method to see what happens.